# SSIS import excel file with merged cells

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, ssis

I have a report in Excel that has to be imported to SQL Server using SSIS.  The file has merged cells which don't seem to import properly.  Instead they show up as NULL.  Does anyone know how to import an Excel file with merged cells?  Thanks.

Comment: How would you expect a merged cell to import?

Comment: @HLGEM : I'd expect that the merged cell would import in one of the merged columns, probably the leftmost one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mapping the correct cell from the Excel spreadsheet?  I've found it should be the first (leftmost) cell that needs to be mapped - if you use the other cell(s) it will come across as null.  Can you add a Data Viewer to the Data Flow Path to check what is coming in?

Comment: I've tried a data viewer right after the excel component and the column is null.

Comment: Does it show up as just one column in the imput?  Usually with merged cells I see both columns (might be named something like F3) in the data flow.